Problem running react-native app via Expo go on ios and android TypeError: Object.groupBy is not a function (it is undefined)
Developing mobile app with React-Native and Expo encounter an issue when try to run code on my ios 15.7.5 iphone 6s and pixel3a emulator on android 12, while web version works fine
  const preData = Object.groupBy(filtredProdList, (prod) => {
    return prod.categories[0].name;
  });


 ERROR  TypeError: Object.groupBy is not a function (it is undefined)

tried some workarounds:

added "node": "^21.6.1" to package.json > dependencies
installed core-js via npm i core-js and then added import { groupBy } from "core-js/actual/array/group-by";
installed npm i typescript@next

additional question is it possible to look somewhere which js function will work and which not?
p.s. - i understand that it is relatively new feature and i could use reduce() instead
